# Chrome mobile: Horizontal scroll not logging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile

This logs the horizontal scroll in chrome desktop but not chrome mobile:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollX = window.scrollX;
    console.log(scrollX);
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, []);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `minimum-scale=1` to the viewport meta tagged solved this for me.